# Comparison between Oracle RAC Cluster Database (10gR2, 11gR2 and 12cR1) and deployed Oracle DB on Linux Cluster

Tags: database, redhat-enterprise-linux, oracle-10g, oracle-11g, oracle-12c

Oracle RAC implementation may be costly for small enterprise, but how it would be if Linux cluster is implemented and then standard Oracle DB is deployed on that cluster to achieve availability like Oracle RAC?

- Is it possible to achieve automatic fail over, load balancing etc. on Linux cluster? If one node fails still Oracle DB service will be served to the existing connections and new connections?
- What can be advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: Might be more on topic for [dba.SE], but only if asking for factual and concrete things, not pros and cons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question will most likely attract opinion based answers. This is one of them.

Load-balancing is not easily available if you run Oracle DB process as a service on a Red Hat cluster. The best you can do when it comes to clustering would be active-standby ie. there would be Oracle DB processes running on only one of the nodes on your cluster at any specific time and processes switch over to another node when one fails. Even that might turn out to be quite difficult to accomplish, though.

The reason why load-balancing scenario is not feasible that way is because having more than one Oracle DB process accessing data partitions without them being aware of each other might corrupt your data. Currently the way to make nodes aware of each other at Oracle DB level is to buy RAC, that's why they sell it.

That said, a active-standby configuration might go something like this: bind Oracle DB processes to an extra IP address which then travels from node to node with the service ie. both service IP address, Oracle DB processes and data partitions are services in a Red Hat cluster, traversing from node to node at failure. The service IP gives you one benefit: fhat way your clients could reconnect when a node fails and another takes its place. However, all existing connections will go down during the switchover in active-standby scenario.

Besides disadvantages listed above, there are other problems as well, e.g. it'll be quite hard to get support from Oracle when something goes wrong as the scenario you're thinking is not exactly one recommended by Oracle.

To sum it up, it might be a good idea to reconsider and if you really need Oracle DB level load-balancing and such, you're probably better off buying RAC than trying to brew your own solution mimicing some of features RAC offers.